# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent выборка связных данных из БД

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Только начал изучать Ларавел. Не пойму как сделать выборку из БД из двух таблиц с foreign key. Если делать простой запрос к БД, то это был бы стандартный left join. Однако хочется воспользоваться Eloquent. Итак:
есть 2 модели:

```
    class Images extends Model
{
    // Table name
    protected $table = 'images';
    // Primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public  $post_id = 'post_id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = array('post_id', 'image_name');

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'id');
    }
}


class Post extends Model
{

    // Table name
    protected $table = 'posts';
    // Primary key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function image()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Images', 'post_id');
    }
```

Не получается вынуть посты с прикрепленными к нему изображениями. Вот контроллер:

```
$posts = Post::with('image')->get();
    var_dump($posts);die;
```

И вот результат выборки:

```
 ["relations":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["image"]=>
    object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#201 (1) {
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
    }
  }
```

Тем не менее я могу найти связанные данные, но только если задать конкретный ID. А мне нужны все посты, с прикрепленными к ним фото, с последующим рендером во вьюху в цикле (аналог Left Join SQL).
Из документации перепробовал все типы связей.

Comment: Включив режим отладки в Eloquent, можно выводить формируемые SQL запросы. Всё ли там правильно формируется?

Comment: Дебаг говорит:
"select * from `posts`"
Это не похоже на связанный запрос )

Comment: Отладьте код и посмотрите что происходит под капотом в Laravel, ну или используйте all вместо get аналогично примеру из документации.

Comment: Спасибо. Весь день этим занимаюсь.
Пока временно решил закрыть проблему вот этим:
$posts = DB::table('posts')
            ->leftJoin('images', 'posts.id', '=', 'images.post_id')
            ->leftJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->select('posts.*', 'users.name', 'images.image_name')
Правда полетела Ajax пагинация. Сейчас буду усиленно читать/смотреть про Eloquent. Здесь большой пробел!

Answer (score 0):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что у вас ошибка в объявлении методов relation
Должно быть

```
public function images()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Images::class,'id', 'post_id');
}
```

и

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

И кстати, что следует помнить, если вы запрашиваете без явного `with('relationName')`, то тогда подгрузка связей произойдет только при явном вызове relation attribute, т.е. например $post->images =) Но в вашем случае подрузка должна произойти на этапе формирования объектов для ответа.